# Weierstrass Approximation Theorem and Real Analytic Functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let there be $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous. Based on this and the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem (WAT), I write:
$$f(x) = \sum_n P_n(x)$$
where $P_n(x)$  are some polinomials.

Now, if I blindly go for the Taylor series of $f$ around some point $x_0 \in[a,b]$, in order to make sure that everything is OK, I have to check if the function is analytic.

What is the difference between the two approaches to writing a function as a series of polynomials and why are there different requirements for each approach?

An example that I did not manage to understand from this point of view is for the function $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ defined, say, on $[-1,1]$. Based on WAT there is a way of writing this function as a sum over some polynomials. However if I try to do it with Taylor series around $x=0$ it fails because it is not analytic.

What am I missing?

Comment: A continuous  $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ can fail to have a derivative at ANY point.There still exists a sequence $(P_n)_n$ of polynomials such that $g_n=\sum_{j=1}^n P_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b],$ but don't expect the sequence to resemble a power series, except that deg$(g_n)$ will $\to \infty.$  Even the function $f(x)=|x|$ is not analytic, and no single power series can equal $ |x|$  at every point of an open interval that contains $ 0 $.

Comment: A Taylor series is a series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)$ but where $P_n(x) = a_n x^n$ is a monomial, very different to a general series of polynomials. The main property of a Taylor series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ is that if it converges at $x_0$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n x_0^n| = 0$ so it converges uniformly and absolutely for $|x| < |x_0|$.

Comment: Some relatively obvious corollaries are that differentiability is not preserved by convergence in the sup norm and that non-differentiable functions are dense in $C[a,b]$.

Comment: @gary Any suggestion for a book that has this covered in greater detail?

Comment: @reuns I don't get it why it counts if the function is written using monomials or any other set of linear independent polynomials. The way I see it is, if i consider the function a vector in an infinite space, the base in which I write the function should not count because I can always change it to fit my purposes.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet What do you mean by 'don't expect the sequence to resemble a power series'. I expected that a sum over some polynomials can be written as a power series based on $P_n=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i$, thus $\sum_{n=0} P_n = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}b_m x^m$

Comment: We can have $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^n A(i,n)x^i$  but that does not mean that each (or any) $A(i,n)$ is independent of n so we cannot write $A(i,n)=B(n).$

Comment: I told you the difference : the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of polynomials doesn't have to be differentiable, while convergent Taylor series are smooth (if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n r^n = 0$ then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ and all its term-wise derivatives converge absolutely for $|x| < r$).